# Setting custom colors when fetching events data using FullCalendar does not seem to work

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I am using the FullCalendar JQuery plugin and fetching the events data via a simple array of events. That works fine, however, I can't seem to set custom colors for those events. I've followed the official documentation. What am I doing wrong? I am trying to set the 'color' and 'textColor' options to be yellow and black like so:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(

    {
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Event1',
                start: '2015-05-04'
            },
            {
                title: 'Event2',
                start: '2015-05-05'
            }
        ],
        color: 'yellow',   // an option!
        textColor: 'black' // an option!
    }
)
```

But, when you visit the [**demo link here**](http://ogmda.com/fullcalendar/demos/default.html), you can see that it does not take effect. Can someone point me in the right direction? The official documentation about doing this method is [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried locally, its working fine...

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(

{
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
     eventSources: [
    {
        events: [ // put the array in the `events` property
            {
                title  : 'event1',
                start  : '2015-05-01'
            },
            {
                title  : 'event2',
                start  : '2015-05-05',
                end    : '2015-05-07'
            },
            {
                title  : 'event3',
                start  : '2015-05-09T12:30:00',
            }
        ],
        color: 'yellow',     // an option!
        textColor: 'black' // an option!
    }

    // any other event sources...

],      
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this require that I will have to set each event's color manually? I won't be able to assign a group of events (like in my first post) a color? I will have like 5-10 different groups of events that will have to have their own group color.

Comment: I edited my answer, its working good now.. please try it.. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/ states:

> The above code should be in a  tag in the head of your page

Have you tried moving the `<script />` code to the head of your page? Currently you have it below your calendar.

Comment: I moved it before I posted my question and noticed no difference. However, thanks for finding that in the docs. Even though it still doesn't affect the color, I moved the code to the head like you stated. Thanks. Any other ideas?